# "Cannot complete this action." error when opening document library folder with spaces in its name

Tags: sharepoint

Following a reorganisation of a document library in Sharepoint (2007) we are seeing the following error message when we try to navigate to a folder that has spaces in its name.

> ### Error
>
> Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again.

Renaming such a folder to remove the spaces in its name cures the issue, but the issue comes back if we re-add the spaces in its name.

Adding a new folder with spaces in its name also causes this issue.

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this bug is resolved with Service Pack 2 of SharePoint 2007. This SP add a bug, it go back to evaluation for 180 days. You need to enter the serial number again in 180 days. How to handle it is documented.

Comment: Do you mean "SP2 fixes the failure of redirection when the redirect URL contains a space"?

Comment: Yes, and it fixed errors whe had when it has french accent

Answer (score 1):

I tried creating a folder with spaces on my local development virtual machine (running version 12.0.0.6219) and it worked without a hitch. What version are you running?

Also, that error message is one of the generic Sharepoint error messages. Try editing your web.config to disable customErrors (or setting it to RemoteOnly if you're on a production server) to see the real error. Alternatively, try checking the log under C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\LOGS for more details.